# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I have an application loaded in my local environment. This is a codebase that I have inherited and have not gotten it to work at all. At this time, when I navigate to "http://test.myapp.com:75/" in my browser, I receive the following error:

*Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I have checked and verified that I have RIA Data Services loaded. I can see the files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server. Interestingly, the assemblies in this directory are not loaded into my GAC. I've tried loading them into my GAC, however, I cannot drag the assemblies into C:\Windows\assembly and no error is shown when I try.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This assembly should already be in the GAC, I'd have to guess at an install problem.  You are looking at the wrong one, the .NET 4 GAC is located in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly.  Drag+drop registration no longer works.  Use fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: So? How to fix that issue?

Answer (score 6):

The Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting library is not part of the standard WCF RIA Services. You have to download and install the [WCF RIA Services **Toolkit**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19663) seperately.

I also recommend reading [WCF Extensibility – Configuring the Endpoint for WCF RIA Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/01/19/wcf-extensibility-configuring-the-endpoint-for-wcf-ria-services.aspx).

Comment: When u install RIA Services seperately it is asking to install at least 3 components more... :(

Comment: Dear https://stackoverflow.com/users/641493/base2 : I need to download this dll but your link at this time is not including the dll. Is another place for downloading this dll individually ?

Comment: @maniaq - See if this works for you. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19663 I also updated the link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem , and solved.

The files "**Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll**" in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server    is the **wrong** one.

The **right** one is here 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server\SP2

I think this problem maybe caursed by the dll file version.
the first one is old and the second one is new .

Answer (score 0):

Setting your .NET version incorrectly in the application list can also create this issue.