# Error in Hosting Site in IIS7

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, hosting

I have hosted Silverlight website in IIS server, but it is giving an error while trying to access it

1) When the application pool is set to ASP.NET Version 4 and managed pipeline in integrated mode, the following error is displayed :

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the
>   currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

2) When the application pool is set to ASP.NET Version 4 and managed pipeline in classic  mode, the following error is displayed:

> HTTP Error 404.2 - Not Found The page you are requesting cannot be
>   served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the
>   Web server.

On further investigation we found out that ISAPI and CGI extension configuration needs to be altered but we were not able to find out the ISAPI & CGI extension option in IIS manager(Version 7.0.6000) manager in Window Server 2008 standard.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028201/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-servicemodel-domainservices-hosting

Comment: If you use 3rd party dlls in Bus project ensure that they are in \bin directory in publish.

Comment: One other thing, although the application pool is set to dot net framework version 4.0, the error is being thrown by dot net framework version 2.0. Is that normal??

Answer (score 0):

In your application, you may have referenced the dll. but while publishing its not being copied I guess. Try right click the same dll and in the properties set `Copy Local`  `True`.
Then publish the solution and Host in IIS.

Comment: Copy Local has been set to true. but still the same error is coming. One other thing, although the application pool is set to dot net framework version 4.0, the error is being thrown by dot net framework version 2.0. Is that normal??